# IDBFactory.onsuccess vs IDBFactory.oncomplete

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, indexeddb

going over a lot of tutorials, and trying things out.

and saw a lot of tutorials showing...

```
window.indexeddb = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
window.transaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
window.keyrange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange
if (!window.indexedDB) {
    window.alert("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB.")
}     
var db;
var opendatabase = window.indexeddb.open("mydatabase", 1);
opendatabase.onsuccess = function(event) {
    db = event.target.result;
    console.log("opendatebase.onsuccess: "+ db);
    somefunction();
};
```

and then go straight into doing reads and writes to indexeddb

should .onsuccess be changed to .oncomplete?

```
opendatabase.oncomplete = function(event) {
    db = event.target.result;
    console.log("opendatebase.onsuccess: "+ db);
    somefunction();
};
```

i would assume opendatabase.oncomplete is fired after fully opening connection?

or is opendatabase.oncomplete fired after all transactions have been completed. and just before db.close() ?

================

this is more geared towards a chrome extension. were having a .open connection 24/7 would most likely be a bad idea.  if indexeddb was created from a given website via javascript it sent to the browser. and only inxededdb only open when you visited that website. that sound good.

but i am questioning having open database connection 24/7 with chrome extension. and i want to make sure any writes to database complete. before db.close is called. from either closing a tab to just closing the browser and shutting the device off.

working towards multi objectstores. and dealing with querys and writes to multi objectstores, at any given time. if improper shut down happens. and only partial data is writen to objectstore_A, but never has a chance to write to objectstore_B on next startup, data could become corrupted and out of sync per say.

link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBFactory

Answer (score 3):

`onsuccess` is related to requests where as `oncomplete` is related to transactions

In your example `opendatabase` is an IDBOpenDBRequest and has no `oncomplete` event.

(And while most of the time your 'requests' are happening against a 'transaction', opening a connection to a database that doesn't require upgrading, is one of the few instances where a request is made with no transaction involved)

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. on were oncomplete could be called for opendatabase. and ability to close out the database.  still learning the ugly raw code of indexeddb and committing it to memory *yikes* was confusing some reading with promises and callbacks for indexeddb, along with yield, and sync vs async. and how to draw out the errors, without them ending up clear at end of } or propagating up the chain.

```
function c(){
    var myadd1 = {id : 1, something : something};
    //1c
    var opendatabase = window.indexedDB.open("mydatabase");
    //2c
    opendatabase.onerror = function(event) {
        console.error("error opening database = " + event)
    }
    //3c
    opendatabase.onblocked = function (event) {
        console.error("error = " + event.target + " close all other open tabs")
    } 
    //4c
    opendatabase.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        // i forgot about this on copy past. not number for this
        var mydatabase = db.createObjectStore("mystore",  {autoIncrement: true, unique :true }); 
        mydatabase.onerror = function(event){
            console.error("mydatabase.error = " + event);
        }
        mydatabase.onsuccess = function(event){
            console.log("mydatabase.onsuccess");
        }
        mydatabase.oncomplete = function(event){
            console.log("mydatabase.oncomplete");
        }
    }
    //5c
    opendatabase.onversionchange = function(event) {
        //db.close();
        alert("A new version of this page is ready. Please close all browser tabs and browser windows and restart your browser!");
    }
    //6c
    opendatabase.onsuccess = function(event) {
        var db = event.target.result;
        console.log("opendatebase.onsuccess: "+ db);
        //7c
        var transaction = db.transaction('mystore', "readwrite");
        //8c
        transaction.onerror = function(event) {
            console.error("trasaction error = " + event);
        }
        //9c
        transaction.onsuccess = function(event){
            console.log("transaction.onsuccess");
            //10c
            var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('mystore');
            //11c
            objectStore.onerror  = function (event) { 
                console.error("objectStore error =" + event );
            }
            //12c
            objectStore.onsuccess = function(event){      
                console.log("objectStore.onsuccess");
                //13c
                var request = objectStore.add(myadd);
                //14c
                request.onerror = function (event) { 
                    console.error("request.add error =" + event);
                }
                //15c
                request.onsuccess = function(event){ 
                    console.log("request.onsuccess");
                    console.log("mysave onsuccess");    
                }
                //16c
                request.oncomplete = function(event) {
                    console.log("request.oncomplete");
                }
            }
            //17c
            objectStore.oncomplete = function(event) {
                console.log("objectStore.oncomplete");
            }
        }
        //18c
        transcation.oncomplete = function(event) {
            console.log("transcation.oncomplate");
        }
    }
    //19c
    opendatabase.oncomplete = function(event){
        console.log("opendatabase.oncomplate");
        var db = event.target.result;
        db.close();
    }
}
```